# Video feedback in processing is extremely slow

Tags: video, processing

I'm new to processing and just created a very simple sketch to grab data from the built-in camera and display it on screen.

```
import processing.video.*;

Capture cam;

void setup() {
  size(640, 480);

  String[] cameras = Capture.list();

  // Take the first available camera
  cam = new Capture(this, cameras[0]);
  cam.start();     

  }      
}

void draw() {
  if (cam.available() == true) {
    cam.read();
  }
  image(cam, 0, 0);
}
```

This works fine, but takes ~17 seconds to open (even when compiled as a standalone) and uses 30% of computer resources thereafter. My computer is by no means underpowered. Have I done something terrible or is processing just slow to handle stuff like this?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Processing (2+)?  What platform are you on?

Comment: I'm using Processing 2.0.3 on Mac OS 10.8.

Comment: Have you considered using openFrameworks?

Comment: Yeah, actually, I ported this to openFrameworks and it opens immediately and takes about 1/6th the resources.